# Localhost MongoDB Connection with Mongoose not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to connect to my MongoDB localhost but it just won't connect. What happens is when I go to `/admin`, it just keeps loading and I get no messages, no nothing in the logs. I have no idea why. This is my router file that uses the connection:

```js
const express = require('express');
const debug = require('debug')('app:adminRouter');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const users = require('../data/users.json');

const adminRouter = express.Router();

adminRouter.route('/').get((req, res) => {
    const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017"; // process.env.DBURL
    const dbName = "workplace_incident_reporter";

    (async function mongo(){
        let client;
        try {
            client = await mongoose.connect(url, 
                { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
            debug('Connected to mongoDB');

            const db = client.db(dbName);

            const response = await db.collection('Users').insertMany(users);
            res.json = response;
        } catch (error){
            debug(error.stack);
        }
    })
});

module.exports = adminRouter;
```

Here is a picture of my MongoDB Compass window. This is only for URL references:
[image: MongoDB Compass Window]

Comment: Is the thing that "isn't working" the fact that you aren't seeing data in Compass? Are you seeing/catching any errors? Where are is the `users` variable (that's passed to `insertMany()`) being defined?

Comment: It's still not clear where `users` are set.  Is it undefined and causing an error? Also, where are you sending back a response to the client? I'm not an express expert, but I don't think I see it in the code you shared (for either the successful or failure states)?

Comment: That's certainly an issue, however I fixed it and I still can't connect to my localhost @user20042973

Comment: Do you get any error? What is the response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the URL from `mongodb://localhost:27017` to `mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017`

Answer (score -1):

Your function mongo doesn't run that way! change it into something like this:

```js
const db_url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017'
const db_main = 'db-main'

const connectDB = mongoose.connect(
  `${db_uri}/${db_main}`,
  {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
  },
  (err) => {
    if (!err) {
      console.log("MongoDB Connection Succeeded.");
    } else {
      console.log("Error in DB connection: " + err);
    }
  }
)
```

Please consider that you can call the mongoDb connection once at the server.js file